# Permutation using probability versus direct frequencies in R?

Tags: r, probability, sampling

I'm trying to understand if there is any difference to the following approaches in permutating values based on their frequencies.

Here is an example of the raw data, which gets binned by `hist`:

```
# generate original data
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
x <- 20 * rlnorm(n, mean=0, sd=0.2)
h <- hist(x)
```

[image]

Now, I am sampling from these binned mid values given their frequencies. The first approach extends a vector first, and then samples with replacement. The second approach used the frequency information in the `prob` argument:

```
# approach 1 - extend value vector by frequencies and then sample with replacement
xs <- rep(h$mids, h$counts)
x1 <- sample(xs, replace = TRUE)

# approach 2 - sample values based on weighted probability with replacement
x2 <- sample(h$mids, size = sum(h$counts), prob = h$counts, replace = TRUE)
```

When I test both approaches in replication, the output looks similar, as I would expect it should be (here I look at the mean and sd of the replicate means):

```
fun1 <- function(x){
  xs <- rep(h$mids, h$counts)
  s <- sample(xs, replace = TRUE)
  mean(s)
}

fun2 <- function(x){
  s <- sample(h$mids, size = sum(h$counts), prob = h$counts, replace = TRUE)
  mean(s)
}

set.seed(1)
F1 <- unlist(lapply(vector("list", 1000), FUN = fun1))
F2 <- unlist(lapply(vector("list", 1000), FUN = fun2))

mean(F1); mean(F2)
# [1] 20.65432
# [1] 20.63858

sd(F1); sd(F2)
# [1] 0.3861233
# [1] 0.3750731
```

So, are these approaches equivalent? I would think that using probabilities is more computationally efficient since one need not first build the vector of values first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code of the `sample` function, the first approach will end using:

```
size <- length(x)
x[sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob)]
```

whilst the second will use:

```
sample.int(x, size, replace, prob)
```

`sample.int` internally calls  `.Internal(sample(n, size, replace, prob))`. Note that the first approaches prob is `NULL` and the seconds one 's is `h$counts`.

To find the definition of the internal function I used the package `pryr`:

```
pryr::show_c_source(.Internal(sample(n, size, replace, prob)))
```

The function `do_sample` can be find [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/3105967d568ce6e411c63a0cbecabaec695b5cc0/src/main/random.c) and also [here](http://docs.rexamine.com/R-devel/main_2random_8c.html#aca442540ab760212c601e4b518651a17).

As the first approach does not contain probabilities, its sampling will be performed using the following part of the `c` code:

```
if (replace || k < 2) {
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) iy[i] = (int)(R_unif_index(dn) + 1);
}
```

The second approach has probabilities, and hence, it uses this part of the  `c` code for the sampling:

```
if (replace) {
  int i, nc = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) if(n * p[i] > 0.1) nc++;
    if (nc > 200)
      walker_ProbSampleReplace(n, p, INTEGER(x), k, INTEGER(y));
    else
      ProbSampleReplace(n, p, INTEGER(x), k, INTEGER(y));
}
```

So the sampling is not exactly the same, but I assume they must be similar. In my opinion, the first one is more straightforward.

Regarding the performance the first one is slightly faster in my computer in this case. I have not tested it for bigger samples, so this can vary. The first approach though has a higher memory allocation, so the use of one or the other should be dependant on the case.

Below I write the code for microbenchmarking in case somebody want to test further:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  F1 <- unlist(lapply(vector("list", 1000), FUN = fun1)),
  F2 <- unlist(lapply(vector("list", 1000), FUN = fun2))
)
```